# Ionic 2 NavController delayed transition

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm using Ionic 2 within my mobile app.
When I transition from the Login page to the Main page (which consist of tabs), rendering takes a little bit too long. Because of this, you see a flicker.

I'm using events to communicate between pages to signal when rendering has completed.

Is there a way to add a page to the navigation stack without starting the transition. 
After I receive the rendering done event, I want to manually start the transition. In other words, is there a way to add a page to the navigation stack in the background?

I'm using Ionic 2 beta 7.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using [lifecycle events](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/nav/NavController/) if you are not already doing so.

I can only assume there's a lot going on in your page constructor and that's why it's taking a bit longer to enter the page. You could move this code to the `onPageWillEnter` event, so that it runs before the page becomes active. Or you could move it to `onPageDidEnter` which will probably translate into a quick transition followed by the dynamic population of your page (this might or might not look awkward in an app depending on how much content will be generated in the event).